# Extracting key pair values inside from a JSON with JQ

Tags: json, jq

I have a part JSON output which looks something like this

```
{
    "data": [{
        "id": "3a7d3f23-edd2-4e14-8e5b-473ccb2d225e",
        "MoreInfo": {
            "Info1": [],
            "Info2": [],
            "localInfo": {
                "id": "6fa2edf0-d034-458d-857e-e86ed14e850f",
                "isExpirationDateCalculated": false,
                "expirationTime": "2021-02-19T18:30:00.000Z"
            },
            "replicationInfos": []
        },
        "vmName": "AD"

    }]
}
```

I am trying to have this formatted like:

> id expirationTime isExpirationDateCalculated

Something that will look like:

```
3a7d3f23-edd2-4e14-8e5b-473ccb2d225e         2021-02-19T18:30:00.000Z    true
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Please include a valid JSON in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I had a part snippet from a lengthy file. Edited with a proper extract.

Comment: It is pretty easy to achieve the expected result using `jq`. Read the [`jq` manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/); it contains examples similar to what you need.

Comment: Thank you. Let me try using this manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ jq -r '.data[0] | [.id, (.MoreInfo.localInfo | .expirationTime, .isExpirationDateCalculated)] | @tsv' tmp.json
3a7d3f23-edd2-4e14-8e5b-473ccb2d225e    2021-02-19T18:30:00.000Z    false
```

Some explanations:

- `.data[0]` selects the object containing `id` from the input.
- `[.id, ...]` creates a new array from the incoming object, consisting of

  - the value associated with `id`
  - the values associated with two of the keys in the object associated with the path `MoreInfo.localInfo`
- The final part takes the previous 3-element array and feeds it to `@tsv`, which outputs a tab-separated string.
- `-r` outputs a raw string, rather than a JSON string (complete with quotation marks).

A simpler, but more repetitive, filter might be

```
[.data[0].id,
 .data[0].MoreInfo.localInfo.expirationTime,
 .data[0].MoreInfo.localInfo.isExpirationDateCalculated] | @tsv
```

Comment: Or just as a list, `.data[0] | [.id, (.MoreInfo.localInfo | .expirationTime, .isExpirationDateCalculated)] | @tsv`?

Comment: Perfect, I though there was a way to do that (like Python `[1, *other_list]`), but blanked on what that way was.